# Question concerning Preimage

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inverse

> Let $f$ be the map from $\mathbb{R} \to \{a,b,c\}$ defined by
>   \begin{equation}
> f(x)=\begin{cases} a &\text{if} \quad x>0 \\ b & \text{if} \quad x<0 \\ c &\text{if} \quad x=0 \end{cases}
> \end{equation}
>   Determine pre-images $f^{-1}(B)$ of all subsets of $B$ and justify if they are closed, open or neither.

**My reasoning**

Let $f$ be a function from $X$ to $Y$. The pre-image of the set $B \subseteq Y$ under $f$ is the subset of $X$ defined by
\begin{equation}
f^{-1}[B]=\{x \in X:f(x) \in B\}
\end{equation}

As such, I would answer $f^{-1}(a)=\mathbb{R}^{+}\backslash \{0\}, f^{-1}(b)=\mathbb{R}^{-1}\backslash \{0\},f^{-1}(c)=0$. As for the second part, I would argue the two first cases are open, as every point in these two subsets are interior point in their respective subset. As for the last case, I interpret the corollary to theorem 2.20 (Rudin, p.33) - *A finite point set has no limit points* - that it is neither open nor closed. **Is any of this correct?**

Comment: What about $f^{-1}\{a,b\}$, etc?

Comment: Also, a set which has no limit points does contain all if its limit points.

Comment: @DavidPeterson Should I include all the combinations $f^{-1}\{a,b\}=\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\},f^{-1}\{a,c\}=\mathbb{R}^{+}, f^{-1}\{b,c\}=\mathbb{R}^{-},f^{-1}\{a,b,c\}=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: There are precisely 8 subsets of $\{a,b,c\}$, assuming that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are all distinct. So there are precisely 8 possible preimages. These will all be the various possible (possibly empty) unions of the sets $\{0\}$, $(-\infty,0)$, and $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: @MPW So I should also include the empty set?

Comment: Absolutely. I think the last line of your problem means to say "all subsets $B$", there is a typo (shouldn't say "all subsets of $B$" because $B$ isn't defined).

Answer (score 1):

Hints： You should consider these cases:

1. $B$ doesn't contain $a,b,c$.  Pre-images $f^{-1}(B)$ is $\emptyset$; Both open and closed.
2. $B$ contains $a,b,c$. Pre-images $f^{-1}(B)$ is $\Bbb R$. Both open and closed.
3. $B$ only contains one element of $\{a,b,c\}$, for example, contains $a$. $f^{-1}(B)=f^{-1}(a)=\mathbb{R}^{+}\backslash \{0\}$. It is open, however not closed.
4. $B$ contains two elesments of $\{a,b,c\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning for the first part is correct. Both $f^{-1}(a)$ and $f^{-1}(b)$ are open.

Concerning $f^{-1}(c)$, here is a hint:

What is the complement of $f^{-1}(c)$? Recall that a set is closed if its complement is open.

One way to reconcile this reasoning with the material in Rudin is by asking yourself (carefully) if every limit point of $f^{-1}(c)$ in $f^{-1}(c)$. If this were not true, then by negating quantifiers, the statement "there exists a limit point of $f^{-1}(c)$ not in $f^{-1}(c)$" would hold. Obviously this is false, since the set of limit points of $f^{-1}(c)$ is empty. Therefore the statement must be true.

Comment: I should have read theorem 2.23 *A set E is open if and only if its complement is closed* more closely.